# Insertion Data with different data type

Tags: mysql, types, phpmyadmin, insert

I have a data column with integer data type.
When I enter a **string** value there is no error and the value is stored `'0'`.

It should not accept this string value.

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

```
INSERT INTO `student`(
    `student_id`,
    `first_name`,
    `last_name`,
    `roll_number`,
    `gender`,
    `date_of_birth`
)
VALUES('std-cs-19-009','f_name','last_name','String',1,1995-06-07)
```

Comment: Which column is integer? Please add your table definition

Comment: roll number is integer, and i am passing a string value to it. and it stores "0". without showing error

Comment: An error is thrown if I use a straight insert if I use insert ignore a warning is thrown and the row is inserted with 0 in the roll_number,

Comment: CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id INT(11),
    first_name CHAR(25),
    last_name CHAR(25),
    roll_number INT(11),
    gender BOOL(1),
    date_of_birth date(???)
);

Comment: That table definition is syntactically incorrect.- there is no bool datatype in mysql and you would also expect an error inserting student_id which is also inserting a string to an int.

Answer (score 0):

During the INSERT, MySQL failed to insert the character value into an INT field so it replaced it with 0 and inserting 0

Comment: Hey Thanx for your reply. But it should not add any value. it should result an error.this 0 is making integrity issues